# How to compare a two list of dict values with one particular value in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, for-loop

I am having two dicts, one in list:

```
var_a = [{'name':"John",'number':21},{'name':"Kevin",'number':23}]
var_b = {'21':"yes"},{'24':"yes"}
```

I need to compare var_a and var_b with the key from var_b with the number value in var_a.

I have tried this and got the output:

```
for key, value in var_b.iteritems():
    for l in var_a:
        if l['number'] == key:
           print l
```

This needs two loops to get the output. So is there any way to finish this is single loop with python 2.7?

Comment: Are the number values unique?

Comment: var_b is a list. you can't do .iteritems() on a list. Please edit your question

Comment: Yes number values are unique@Nick

Comment: Yes, edited @Pani

Comment: Even after your edit you have `var_b = {'21':"yes"},{'24':"yes"}` which means that `var_b` is a tuple of two dictionaries. Did you mean `var_b = {'21':"yes",'24':"yes"}` ?

Comment: Yes@ArthurTacca

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to create a keys set from `var_b` keys and then loop only over `var_a` to check if the number value exists in the `var_b` keys set

```
var_a = [{'name':"John",'number':21},{'name':"Kevin",'number':23}]
var_b = [{'21':"yes"},{'23':"no"}]

keys_set = set(map(lambda x: int(list(x.keys())[0]), var_b))
for i in var_a:
    if i['number'] in keys_set:
        print(i)
```

Output

```
{'name': 'John', 'number': 21}
{'name': 'Kevin', 'number': 23}
```

Comment: This code will create a set of each key of dictionary that in `var_b` list by the map method that taking an iterable and applying a function (on each item in the iterable) in my case lambda function that extracting all the keys and then looping over `var_a` items and checking if the number value of the item is in the `var_b` keys set and if so it's printing the `var_a` item.

Comment: @Navi you do realise `map` is a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the lambda function with one for-loop:

```
for key, value in var_b.iteritems():
    result = filter(lambda d: d['id'] == key, var_a)
```

The result will give you the output for sure.

Comment: @Navi you do realise `filter` is a loop?

Comment: It is faster than a for loop@Nick